# Setting the Content-Transfer-Encoding of upload file in multi-part HTTP request part with Apache HttpClient

Tags: java, apache, http, multipart

I am using apache http library to build and send a multi-part http request that has a file part in the body. Here is a little sample of my request

```
Request POST HTTPS://hostname:9443/di/resources/upload?logonId=user1 HTTP/1.1:
 Headers: Content-Type: multipart/form-data  Set-Cookie: Path=/; HttpOnly  TrustToken: -1000%2CCaKOjiTFmje3%2Fw0GGcw5%2BDwgxXHjHdQShQgW1QGiHYk%3D  
 Body: --ncFZGuKp50zCWWImlBFZjxbanSSoJt
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="File 1"; filename="SampleData_en.csv"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

Identifier,title,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Plan: Entries (1) or ent2 (2) ,2,"Set to 1 to specify plan is for Catalog Entries, set to 2 etc ..... 

--ncFZGuKp50zCWWImlBFZjxbanSSoJt--
```

The project is that the service is based on apache wink that has a problem decoding the headers in the body which gives this kind of error

```
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
        at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1240)
        at org.apache.wink.common.internal.providers.multipart.MultiPartParser.parseHeaders(MultiPartParser.java:264)
        at org.apache.wink.common.internal.providers.multipart.MultiPartParser.nextPart(MultiPartParser.java:109)
        at org.apache.wink.common.model.multipart.InMultiPart.hasNext(InMultiPart.java:83)
```

I believe the fix would be to remove the Content-Transfer-Encoding from the body? or change it to maybe a different encoding, maybe base64.

The only problem is that I dont know how to do this using the apache library and haven't been able to find anything examples. Here is the code I am using apache to create the entity portion of my HttpPost request:

```
MultipartEntityBuilder reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

File file1 = RequestUtils.getFileBody(filePath);
FileBody fileBodyFile1 = new FileBody(file1, org.apache.http.entity.ContentType.create("application/octet-stream"),
file1 .getName());
reqEntity.addPart("File 1", fileBodyFile1);
```

Comment: if you may consider using another [http client](http://bayou.io/release/0.9/docs/http/Http_Client.html#Form_Submission)

Comment: sorry not really an option for me :( thanks for the suggestion. I am still hoping that what I am asking for is possible with apache